# Universal Remote Question

Tags: ipod-touch, remote-control

I'm looking for the mid-price point universal remote to control a Visio TV + Blue Ray (Samsung)+Comcast Cable Box + Panasonic Stereo.  I would like touch screen if possible with easy setup.  Price is a secondary issue but I don't want to pay like $500.00 dollars...  Any Suggestions?  It could be iPod Touch related, or PC-based?

Comment: Jared Harley is a "god" in my eyes.  I purchased this controller, set it up, and it worked correctly from first push!  New egg had the controller for $39.00 dollars?.  The one push to watch TV or DVD which includes turning on 4 pc. of equipment worked flawlessly Great advice, I love this site guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using a [Logitech Harmony H-659](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0003QER82) remote for several years and absolutely love it.

The Harmony remote series come with software (or you can download it from their site) that allows you to configure your Harmony remote through USB. You create an account, and Logitech stores your remote configuration so that you can reload it onto your remote whenever you need. I never thought that it was a useful feature until I broke my H659 and bought a new one - it took 2 minutes to upload the configuration, and it was like nothing had changed!

Logitech stores the remote codes for thousands of devices, so there is no "try code xxx1, power, nope, try code xxx2, nope, etc". It's just a matter of picking your device from the software and letting it upload it to the remote.

The Harmony remote series also has an extremely high "[wife approval factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wife_acceptance_factor)" (or WAF). You can set up actions like "Watch a Movie", which, on my setup, sets the speakers to the PC input, changes the TV to HDMI1, and turns on the PC.

[image: Logitech remote]

Comment: I own the Harmony 670 (http://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Harmony-670-Universal-Remote/dp/B000IMSK8Y) and love it. Pretty much any Harmony remote is worth getting and the WAF is a definite plus!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&safe=off&q=logitech+harmony&cid=18245116420118598431&sa=title#p

They are about $300, but you won't find a slicker remote control anywhere. And it's under your threshold of $500

The application to program it is PC based and very easy to program for a ton of devices.

Comment: I want one of them.  There are also cheaper more normal Harmony remotes, if $300 is a bit steep still.

Comment: The Harmony units are awesome. They aren't that hard to program, and once they are set up, they just work. I've seen some of the lower-end one for around $100, but they don't have the really nice displays.

Comment: Yeah, the cheaper one's aren't touch screen, but are highly programmable.